# Kill process by name and user

Tags: process, kill

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to kill all processes by name and user. E.g. I want to kill all the Java instances run by user myuser.

As of the moment I do:

```
$ pgrep -u myuser java
2185
3281
3413
3504
22534
26174
27554
```

which gives a list of the pid of java run by mysuer. Then I kill each pid individually. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`killall(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall):

```
killall -u myuser java
```

Note that you may need to do this via `sudo`, and you may need `-9` to kill processes that swallow `SIGTERM`:

```
sudo killall -9 -u myuser java
```

Comment: ok, sorry. I tried it on java before, but top was still showing the java pid and the recources it was using. To retry it again, I just started several instances of top and tried to use that command to kill all of them for my user, but a new top window still shows 5 top processes running.

Comment: thanks, that works. Tried all kind of command with kill, killall and pkill with -9 and SIGTERM, but seem to have missed that one.

Comment: @Oli: out of curiosity, what exactly does -9 add to the command? I read its for alternate signals, but do you know what is actually does?

Comment: @evgeni: 9 is the number for `SIGKILL`.  An application cannot provide a custom handler for `SIGKILL` (or ignore it), so the application will always terminate immediately (unless it is a zombie process).  In contrast, `kill` and `killall` send `SIGTERM` by default, which *can* be caught by the application.

Answer (score 1):

following command can do the job

```
$ pkill -u user process_name
```

note that process_name can be a regular expression also.

Answer (score 0):

You're close:

```
$> pgrep -u myuser java | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here it is an bash script to doing this easily...:

```
`pgrep -u root $app`
set -- $appPID
kill -9 $appPID
```

Here it's a blog post I wrote about this topic for killing a group of processes : https://soroo.sh/linux/kill-processess-by-name

Answer (score 0):

You can  do this by using

```
killall -u user
```

But sometimes this  will result in a  defunct process.

The  best  way  could  be  like  this :-

```
psu | grep user | awk  '{print $2}' | xargs   kill -9
```

NOTE :- this will  also  kill your current logged in session on the server if  you are  killing processes  started by the user which you are logged on.

Thanks.